# Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '[CDYelpPriceTier]?'

Tags: xcode10, yelp, swift4.2

I am working on an app that requires me to make a call from yelp. In the yelp call, I want to replace the `[.oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns] with "pricestring"`.
I get the following error when I change the code to `priceTiers: pricestring`

**Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '[CDYelpPriceTier]?'**

```
//Array declaration  
         var pricestring = [String]()

         //Set pricestring
          pricestring.append(".oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns")
        //Yelp Call
            yelpAPIClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Food",
                 ....

            priceTiers: [.oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns], <----

            attributes: nil)
```

From the CDYelpFusionKit Documentation:

```
 price: (Optional) The pricing levels to filter the search result with. 
 Use the **CDYelpPriceTier** enum to get the list of supported pricing levels. 
 `price` can be an array of pricing levels (e.g. [.oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns, .threeDollarSigns] will filter the results to show businesses that are listed as $, $$, or $$$).
```

What do I have to do to be able to replace the [.oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns] with a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
//Array declaration
var priceLevels = [CDYelpPriceTier]()
```

Set

```
//Set pricestring
priceLevels.append(contentsOf: [.oneDollarSign, .twoDollarSigns])
```

and use it

```
, ... priceTiers: priceLevels, ...
```